# Is there any guarantee that complex<Type> object's imaginary part is set to zero when a real number is input?

Tags: c++

In my environment (g++ 5.4.0), a code

```
complex<double> cmp;
cin >> cmp; //input 3 or (3) (not (3,0))
cout << "cmp = " << cmp << "\n";
```

gives me the result:

```
cmp = (3,0) //imaginary part is automatically set to 0
```

Does anyone have a written evidence which guarantee this behavior? N4140 (§ 26.4.6-12; p.921) says

```
 Effects: Extracts a complex number x of the form: u, (u), or (u,v), 
          where u is the real part and v is the imaginary part (27.7.2.2).
```

but this doesn't imply that the input of the form `u` or `(u)` makes the object's imaginary part `0`.

You can see this behavior in a reliable MSDN's example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/mt771459.aspx#operator_gt__gt_) but even this doesn't make an explicit explaination.

The draft says "`u` is the real part", and I input only the real part. I think there is an ambiguity in deciding what kind of value is set to imaginary part. Of course, `u`'s imaginary part is `0`, but this guarantees nothing, I think.

Comment: Not sure to understand your doubt, but looking at the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/complex), you'll see that the imaginary part has a default value T().

Comment: @Bob__ When `>>` is used, is the constructor called? Could you give me what page of standard document says so?

Comment: In this line `complex<double> cmp;` was called constructor, `complex (const T& re = T(), const T& im = T())` so if T is float/double default value of `im` is 0.0 .

Comment: @rafix07 That is just an initial `im` value. Even if you write `complex<double> cmp(3,4);`, imaginary part is set to `0` though you only input the real part.

Comment: @BoPersson Thank you. I read the report. Now I'd like to select your comment as the "accepted answer" if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention of the standard is likely that it should work, even if the text when scrutinized doesn't explicitly say so. And in practice the code will work with the known implementations.

There is an existing defect report requesting the committee to clarify that its intention *is* what is already implemented:

[#2714 complex stream extraction underspecified](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2714)

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the implementation (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00812_source.html)

```
00486   template<typename _Tp, typename _CharT, class _Traits>
00487     basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&
00488     operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& __is, complex<_Tp>& __x)
00489     {
00490       _Tp __re_x, __im_x;
00491       _CharT __ch;
00492       __is >> __ch;
00493       if (__ch == '(') 
00494     {
00495       __is >> __re_x >> __ch;
00496       if (__ch == ',') 
00497         {
00498           __is >> __im_x >> __ch;
00499           if (__ch == ')') 
00500         __x = complex<_Tp>(__re_x, __im_x);
00501           else
00502         __is.setstate(ios_base::failbit);
00503         }
00504       else if (__ch == ')') 
00505         __x = __re_x;
00506       else
00507         __is.setstate(ios_base::failbit);
00508     }
00509       else 
00510     {
00511       __is.putback(__ch);
00512       __is >> __re_x;
00513       __x = __re_x;
00514     }
00515       return __is;
00516     }
```

you can see that in the case where `s` or `(s)` is the format that you type on the keyboard `__x` which is your complex gets assigned to `__re_x` (either lines 505 or 513) which we can think of it as a `double` for simplicity.

A rapid look at the `operator=` tells you that the imaginary part is default constructed.

```
00230     complex<_Tp>::operator=(const _Tp& __t)
00231     {
00232      _M_real = __t;
00233      _M_imag = _Tp();
00234      return *this;
00235     }
```

This means that your only guarantee is that the imaginary part will be default constructed (on GCC).  For most types this translates to `0` initialized.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the specific implementation. I read the code and understand the meaning. However, this doesn't guarantee the portability of my code. This guarantees only `If I compile my code with g++ (or gcc?), the imaginary part is set to 0`.